# Absolute path link with Markdown?

Tags: markdown

H_i guys is there a way to create absolute path links with markdown ? I've tried the

1.`[link](/home/path/to/file)` markdown syntax

and also the html way :

2.`<a href="home/path/to/file"> link </a>`

But when I click on the link ( on Atom via the markdown-preview-enhanced plugin or threw chromium ) it's understood as relative path so it points to "/MyActualMdFileFolder/home/path/to/file" which obviously doesn't exist. Btw I'm editing my .md files threw atom and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

`[link](file:///path/to/file)` isn't at all recognized as a link

but  the HTML equivalent works fine :

`<a href = "file:///path/to/file"> link </a>`