# display local image in markdown

Tags: r, image, web, import

Can anyone help me to display an image in markdown?
I tried this:
![Distribution](/Users/michaelwiseman/Desktop/Test Website/my_website/content/distribution.png)

It displays the image in the index.Rmd panel, but displays only the text "Distribution" in the viewer.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395804/absolute-path-link-with-markdown

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Path is wrong.
You could try it with a relative path (relative to the *.md File).
Like this:

```
![Distribution](distribution.png)
```

In this case, the image and the md file should be in the same Directory.
Or a little bit cleaner with images in a Folder "media":

```
![Distribution](media/distribution.png)
```